# Elegant wait to async/await for some value change

Tags: javascript, async-await

Imagine I have some property (could also be a method call that returns a boolean) in a third party library (not in my code) like:

```
somelib.ready
```

This property gets changed by some async code I cannot wait for (not exposed), so I was thinking if there is some nice, elegant library that will wait for this to change up to a timeout?

I would love to write something like:

```
await waitForWrapper(() => someLib.ready, 100, 1000);
```

Signature would be something like

```
waitForWrapper(checkCalllback, pollTime, timeout)
```

I know I could write this, it is just a few lines of code with the setTimeout->Promise wrapper and using two setTimeouts properly, but I am rather asking if there is some "popular" library that solves this kind of stuff so that I do not need to be writing this kind of helper code...

Comment: `someLib.ready` is *not* a variable, though. It's an object property.

Comment: Where is the "some async code" ? Is it an internal method of the 3rd party code or is it exposed to the outside  ?

Comment: @Dilshan if it was exposed, I would await for that... ;) This is a typical case, I have run across this kind of stuff many times, just looking for something "standard" to handle this kind of not so nice implementations...

Comment: @VLAZ, you are right, if it was a variable declared by myself, the question would not make any sense... ;)

Comment: `someLib`.doesn't have some `onreadystatechange` method to attach handlers when the `ready` value changes?

Comment: Technically there should be an event `onready` as @adiga asked. Otherwise there's no usage from the `ready` variable. Or else, `ready` should be an observable or the setter of `ready` should emit an event. Maybe you can add a library reference you see this issue.